# Error 1004 en una macro

Tags: excel, vba, macros

He creado la siguiente macro:

```
Sub Extraer1()
'Definir origen y destino que utilizaremos
Dim OrigenHoja As Excel.Worksheet, _
    DestinoHoja As Excel.Worksheet, _
    OrigenCelda As Excel.Range, _
    DestinoCelda As Excel.Range

'Definir las hojas origen y destino
   Set OrigenHoja = Worksheets("Origen")
   Set DestinoHoja = Worksheets("Destino")

'Definir las celdas origen y destino
Const celdaOrg = "A1"
Const celdaDst = "A1"

'Indicar los rangos origen y destino
Set OrigenCelda = OrigenHoja.Range(celdaOrg)
Set DestinoCelda = DestinoHoja.Range(celdaDst)

'Seleccionar los rangos
ActiveSheet.Unprotect
OrigenCelda.Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.Copy

'Pegar en destino
DestinoCelda.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Cuando ejecuto me muestra el error '1004' en tiempo de ejecución. Error en el método Select de la clase Range.

Alquien me puede decir donde se encuentra el error.

Gracias.

Comment: Muchas Gracias!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes activar antes la hoja en la que está el Rango `OrigenCelda`.

Justo antes de `ActiveSheet.Unprotect` escribe `OrigenHoja.Activate`

Comment: Muchas Gracias. Problema resuelto!!!

Comment: Genial. Si te ha servido la respuesta, por favor, márcala como correcta, y así se queda cerrada la pregunta.